# Unexpected error: "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to access a list within a function

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, index-error

```
def myMax(L):
    print(L)
    f=len(L)
    ind=0
    maxx=L[0]
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i]>maxx:
             maxx=L[i]
             ind=i
    return (ind,maxx)
print(myMax([1, 2, -9, 10]))
print(myMax([]))
```

I am quite new to python. Above is code that I have written which takes a list as input and returns a tuple with the index of the highest number and the highest number itself.

For some reason I am getting an "IndexError:list index out of range" on line 5, where "maxx=L[0]"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You pass an empty array, so it doesn't have anything on index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass empty list : `myMax([])` to the function and you point to the first element of this empty list `L[0]`. You need to check if the list `L` is not empty.

Adding the below as the first lines of the function will help you to protect against None or empty list

```
if L is None or len(L) == 0:
  raise ValueError('Input list can not be None or empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the function on an empty list on the last line of your code.

```
   print(myMax([]))
```

The argument you are passing to myMax function is [] that have length of zero.
When you call the fifth line your are actually trying to access the first element of the list, that does exist. In fact list in Python are indexed from 0 to n - 1 where n is the size of the list.

By default when you try to access an array on an index that it does not contain, the interpreter raise the exception `IndexError: list index out of range`. There are several ways to handle this cases for example the `try` `except` control, but in your case since the function in returning an integer I suggest you to append a control at the very end in order to return -1 in such cases.

```
    def myMax(L):
        if len(L) == 0:
            return -1
        # your code here
```

In this way you will not try an out of bound access and you have a return code representing the error occurred.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).